# How to configure timeout for javascript in VF?

Tags: visualforce, timeout

I am begging at Salesforce. I'm having the exception *"Unable to connect to the server (transaction aborted: timeout)."*

This happens when try to put more than 300 orderitems into an order.

I saw in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm) that I have to include `{ buffer: true, escape: true, timeout: 120000 }` in the remoting request in the VisualForce. But I guess It don't have a remoting request... So I confused, I don't know where I have to put `{ buffer: true, escape: true, timeout: 120000 }`.

```html
<apex:page controller="OrderFinishController">
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/46.0/integration.js"/>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="associate"></div>
    <script>
    
    
    var callCloseTab = function callCloseTab(result) {
        sforce.console.closeTab(result.id);
    }        
    function closeTab(value) {
        if (value == "true") {
            setTimeout(function() {
                sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(callCloseTab);
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Tab wont close because value returned isn't >true< | value: " + value);
        }
    }
    
    function closeTabHandler(event) {        
        redirectControllerCall();
    }
    
    function openNewTabHandler(event) {
        var eventValue = event.getParam('data');
        if (eventValue == "true" || eventValue == "false") {
            return;
        }
        openTab(null, eventValue);
    }
    
    function openTab(id, url) {
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(id, url, true);
    }
    
    
    window.onload = function() {
        $Lightning.use("c:OrderFinishApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:OrderFinish",
                                       {},
                                       "associate",
                                       function(cmp) {
                                           console.log('>>>>> App is hosted');
                                           $A.eventService.addHandler({"event": "c:CloseConsoleTabExternalEvent",
                                                                       "handler" : closeTabHandler });
                                           var getThisTabId = function getThisTabId(result) {
                                               cmp.set("v.cTabId", result.id);
                                               console.log("cTabId >> " + result.id);
                                           }  
                                           sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(getThisTabId);
                                       });
        });
    }
    </script>
    
    <apex:form >    
        <apex:actionFunction name="redirectControllerCall" action="{!redirect}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Deleting and re-asking questions is frowned upon, and don't get rid of downvotes. If you continue to do this, the stackexchange software itself will prevent you from asking further questions (and that's not something our mods can reverse).

Comment: I was just trying to explain it better, since the other question wasn't clear. sorry